# How to dynamically add/remove additional listen URLs to Kestrel at runtime after server is started?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I want to be able to add/remove ports on the Kestrel listens on after the web server has been started (something you would normally configure via `UseUrls` method in IWebHostBuilder. I don't want to restart the entire web server in the process as I need to keep servicing any existing requests on other ports. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems that you can do it like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configureiconfiguration, dynamically updating the configuration (I assume the configuration is not necessarily coming from a file, you can control it programmatically). However I don't have a running proof of concept.